# scrapy - dont understand where this json comes from

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on my first crawler with scrapy and trys to get all images without alt="" attribute.
so my crawler finds all the images without alt, but gives me json item i dont understand. here is an example json output:

```
[
 "[\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAA///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=\"]",
 "[\"https://tobier.de/media/2018/06/logo2-1.png\"]",
 "[\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=\"]",
 "[\"https://tobier.de/media/2018/07/12548893_1089313591090351_8553746080250989501_n.jpg\"]",
 "[\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=\"]",
 "[\"https://tobier.de/media/2018/07/16729432_1368587256496315_1586875734109631011_n.jpg\"]"
]
```

My Question: 
What are the `"data:image/gif..."` items and why are they there?

My Python Code for the images:

```
def getImages(self, response):
    images = response.xpath('//img')
    imagesWithout = []
    for img in images:
        alt = img.xpath('./@alt').extract()
        if not alt:
           imagesWithout.append( img.xpath('./@src').extract() )
    return json.dumps(imagesWithout)
```

Edit:
On the crawled [Website](https://tobier.de/wordpress-custom-post-type/), is no image-tag base64 src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lookup the source code of the page (this should work with chrome and firefox):

```
view-source:https://tobier.de/wordpress-custom-post-type/
```

you have this for example

```
<img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" data-lazy-src="https://tobier.de/media/2018/07/wordpress-custom-post-type-1.png" alt="wordpress custom post type" itemprop="contentUrl"/>
```

That is the first one you get in your json.

Might be some Wordpress specific images.

Comment: omg...i dosnt see it, because i was logged in and my caching plugin makes this for normal users. thanks!

Comment: @Tobias Maybe debugging in incognito mode might help with that kind of issues

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the code does what it's meant to.

The unfamiliar src tags are a trick described in detail [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

I went to the webpage link and found at least one img with data in base 64

`<span class="ez-toc-section" id="Permalinks_aktualisieren">Permalinks aktualisieren</span></h3><p>Erstellen wir im Backend nun einen Mitarbeiter, sehen wir unter dem Title den Permalink. Wie konfiguriert, wird zwischen der Domain und dem Mitarbeiter-Name nun der Slug &#8222;mitarbeiter&#8220; ausgegeben.</p><figure class="figure" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"> <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" data-lazy-src="https://tobier.de/media/2018/07/permalink.png" alt="post type permalink" itemprop="contentUrl"/>`

Comment: Yay, downvoted for giving a correct answer! Makes me love stackoverflow.